# Select Company or organization: Did I mean Google? Or Google? Or maybe Google? Perhaps I meant Google? Or one of another two Googles? I have no idea

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Did I mean:

[image: 6 suggestions, all of them Google]

I don't know. There's no way to tell what, if any, the difference is.

Comment: I so want to close this as 'Unclear what you are asking' :)

Comment: The real shock would have been if that only showed Microsoft logo's ...

Comment: ..or GitHub....

Comment: But why Zagat? How does that make sense?

Comment: Google owned Zagat until about 3 months ago @Catija

Comment: @Shog9 It's still confusing why it would show the corporate name rather than the company name. Would Marvel Studios show up as Disney instead?

Comment: So I guess they *do* have Google where you live?

Comment: it's clear that the second *google* is the good one ...

Comment: Best. Title. EVER

Comment: Did you try to Google it?

Comment: This screenshot is inscrutable: Can you add a (freehand) circle so I can tell what you're trying to show?

Comment: I don't think you want to pick any of those. You should pick Google instead.

Comment: Now just imagine if there were a google different suggestions.

Comment: The title intrigued me and I was not disappointed by the image.

Comment: So you work at Google or Google? Or third option, Google?

Comment: This is one case where I wish LMGTFY wasn't banned...

Comment: Anywhere else, Google gathers information on you. On stack Overflow, you gather Google.

Comment: For me, this works fine: http://i63.tinypic.com/2mqs4k1.png

Comment: It's pretty simple: google is google, google is google, google is google, and  google is google. You can research for yourself what google, google, google and google are.

Comment: I guess this answers how many Googles would a Google google if a Google could google Googles.

Comment: Why not Alphabet Inc. ?

Comment: I tried googling this and I think I broke Google. Chuck Norris, halp!!

Comment: To replace this image with a better image, I made this. It includes freehand circles as requested https://i.imgur.com/Ppm7ecz.png Please use it took a long time to make. @TemporalWolf

Comment: @Catija Trying Marvel brings up a different issue, a [broken image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iKou.png)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jr4jkv Here, try this.

Comment: Doh forgot to `DISTINCT` it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We built the List feature soon after we released the Developer Story. It primarily tried to achieve two objectives:

1. Help users add items to their developer story more quickly by autocompleting some fields
2. Show profiles of other SO users that share the same developer story item

Lists are essentially just Name, Url, and Image Url combinations that other users have added to their developer story.

We wanted to give users who created a CV on Stack Overflow (pre-developer story) a way to attach their existing items to a list, so we built this quick and dirty list suggestion feature that you are referring to. When a user edits an existing story item, we provide possible list suggestions, primarily to achieve objective 2 and bring general awareness to the list feature.

Admittedly this feature was not iterated upon and did not amount to anything very useful. However, we have been in talks about replacing this lists feature altogether with company pages.

For the time being, we'll remove this list suggestion feature when editing story items, but keep it when adding new story items.

Thanks very much for your report.

Answer (score 5):

Where are you seeing these duplicates?

I see three entries for "Google" when adding a new position to my [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current?ac=1) page. There are a few entries for Google in other countries, although most of them only list a single member.

[image: Duplicate developer story pages]